In Oracle: How to sort by group/cluster by a column value
Here is a sample of my data
select * from (
    select 'A' as POD, 164 as result from dual union all
    select 'A' as POD, 3 as result from dual union all
    select 'A' as POD, 2 as result from dual union all
    select 'B' as POD, 409 as result from dual union all
    select 'B' as POD, 128 as result from dual union all
    select 'B' as POD, 5 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 12391 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 624 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 405 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 26 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 3 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 2 as result from dual
)





POD
RESULT




A
164


A
3


A
2


B
409


B
128


B
5


C
12391


C
624


C
405


C
26



And what I want is for them to be sorted by group with highest first count:



POD
RESULT




C
12391


C
624


C
405


C
26


B
409


B
128


B
5


A
164


A
3


A
2



I am not even sure how to express this as SQL
C has the highest result in the first row, then B has the next highest then A

Please explain precisely what leads to showing C before B before A.

updated for clarity

I understand the task as follows:

Look at the pods' results. Show the pod with the highest result first, then the pod with the next highest, etc.
Order the rows in each pod by result descending.

Now, what do we consider the highest result? Is this the maximum result per pod? That would be A = 164, B = 409, C = 12391. We would get this with
MAX(result) OVER (PARTITION BY pod)

Or is it the maximum result sum per pod? That would be A = 169, B = 542, C = 13446. And the expression we'd need is
SUM(result) OVER (PARTITION BY pod)

Use one or the other in your ORDER BY clause. E.g.:
SELECT pod, result
FROM mytable
ORDER BY
  MAX(result) OVER (PARTITION BY pod) DESC,
  pod,
  result DESC;


@Salman Arshad: Thank you for the edit.

Ok, you actually answers some follow on questions I was going to have in addition to the one asks (part 3)

another way is by using the row_number in this way to sort your data desc:
select * from (
    select 'A' as POD, 164 as result from dual union all
    select 'A' as POD, 3 as result from dual union all
    select 'A' as POD, 2 as result from dual union all
    select 'B' as POD, 409 as result from dual union all
    select 'B' as POD, 128 as result from dual union all
    select 'B' as POD, 5 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 12391 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 624 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 405 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 26 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 3 as result from dual union all
    select 'C' as POD, 2 as result from dual
)
order by last_value(result) OVER (PARTITION BY pod order by result rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) desc, result desc

Hope it helps.

This definitely works

@Christian Bongiorno: It "works", but it doesn't do what you want. And it is unnecessarily complicated. order by pod desc, result desc does the same thing, only much easier to read. And you don't want to sort your rows by the pod in reverse alphabetical order anyway. You want to sort the pods by their results.
